# Finding the product key and more in Windows XP and later?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

In Windows XP and later, is there a way to find...

- Product key
- Owner and Company information
- Device drivers
- Windows version
- List of users

and more in the Windows registry? I'm asking because I'm writing a little gift for my boss (I work at a computer repair center.) that will automate the process of backing up a users data and reinstalling Windows from a modified Ubuntu live CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Former repair technician here. The easiest way to do all of this may be to boot WinPE from, say, [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) (which can be [installed to a USB thumbdrive](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk), hint-hint).

1, 2, 4: There's a program on Hiren's for that.

3: I am unsure of the best way to back-up drivers but it is usually advisable to install the latest versions anyhow.

5: Load the registry hives  and look at HKEY_USERS, the same place the User Profiles dialog is populated from in XP. It is the "right" way rather than looking at the Documents and Settings folder.

Hiren's Boot CD has **so much more functionality**, including a copy of Ghost (which you must have an existing license to use) and tons of other software.

Hope this has been helpful!

Comment: True, Hiren's bootcd is wonderful, but the reason I asked about items 1, 2, and 4 is to create the unattend.txt file to do an unattended windows install.

Comment: In that case, my response above is largely useless. I would explore [the library used by Offline NT](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/editor.html) or use their `reged` utility. It looks like extraction of the product key needs to be performed under Windows, though (i.e. Wine).